# Normals being weird

Tags: normals

[image]

How do I fix the part circled in green? And why are there those red spots in the yellow circles? (I already tried recalculating the normals)

Comment: Where did your model come from? - It looks as if the topology may be very poor but it's difficult to tell without seeing your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link to it and then edit your question and paste the link into it.

Comment: Those aren't by any chance holes? Are you seeing through to the other side of the mesh? ( I wonder if/why I'm seeing a Solid-Mode outline ?)